# get boundaries of complex object in image with white background (js)

Tags: javascript, image-processing, canvas, three.js

What is a good way of getting the boundaries for an image (not the image itself, but rather the non-white pixels)? I am using javascript, so try to keep the algos within that realm if you can.

For example, how would I get a list/two lists of all of the x and y points where for the points that exist on the boundary of this (group of) object(s):

[image]

Note that the interior part should be included, but a lack of colour that is completely on the inside (like a hole) should be excluded.

Therefore, the result would be two lists that contain the x and y points (for the pixels) that would construct an object similar to this:

[image]

Below is how I "achieved" it. While it works for all concave objects, if you try to use it for more complex objects with some convex sides, it inevitably fails.

### Success with Concave Object

- jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/bhc4qn87/

snippet:

```js
var _PI = Math.PI, _HALF_PI = Math.PI / 2, _TWO_PI = 2 * Math.PI;
var _radius = 10, _damp = 75, _center = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0);
var _phi = _PI / 2, _theta = _theta = _PI / 7;
var _sceneScreenshot = null, _dirty = true;

var _tmpCan = document.createElement("canvas"),
 _tmpCtx = _tmpCan.getContext("2d");

var scene = document.getElementById("scene"),
 sw = scene.width, sh = scene.height;
var _scene = new THREE.Scene();
var _renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ canvas: scene, alpha: true, antialias: true });
_renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
_renderer.setSize(sw, sh);
var _camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(35, sw / sh, .1, 1000);

_tmpCan.width = sw; _tmpCan.height = sh;

_scene.add(new THREE.HemisphereLight(0x999999, 0x555555, 1));
_scene.add(new THREE.AmbientLight(0x404040));
var _camLight = new THREE.PointLight(0xdfdfdf, 1.8, 300, 2);
_scene.add(_camLight);

var geometry = new THREE.BoxBufferGeometry( 1, 1, 1 );
var material = new THREE.MeshPhysicalMaterial( { color: 0x2378d3, opacity: .7 } );
var cube = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
_scene.add( cube );

function initialize() {
 document.body.appendChild(_tmpCan);
 _tmpCan.style.position = "absolute";
 _tmpCan.style.left = "8px";
 _tmpCan.style.top = "8px";
 _tmpCan.style.pointerEvents = "none";
 addListeners();
 updateCamera();
 animate();
}

function addListeners() {
 /* mouse events */

 var scene = document.getElementById("scene");

 scene.oncontextmenu = function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
 }

 scene.onmousedown = function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  mouseTouchDown(e.pageX, e.pageY, e.button);
 }

 scene.ontouchstart = function(e) {
  if (e.touches.length !== 1) {
   return;
  }
  e.preventDefault();
  mouseTouchDown(e.touches[0].pageX, e.touches[0].pageY, e.touches.length, true);
 }

 function mouseTouchDown(pageX, pageY, button, touch) {
  _mouseX = pageX; _mouseY = pageY;
  _button = button;
  if (touch) {
   document.ontouchmove = function(e) {
    if (e.touches.length !== 1) {
     return;
    }
    mouseTouchMove(e.touches[0].pageX, e.touches[0].pageY, e.touches.length, true);
   }
   document.ontouchend = function() {
    document.ontouchmove = null;
    document.ontouchend = null;
   }
  } else {
   document.onmousemove = function(e) {
    mouseTouchMove(e.pageX, e.pageY, _button);
   }
   document.onmouseup = function() {
    document.onmousemove = null;
    document.onmouseup = null;
   }
  }
 }

 function mouseTouchMove(pageX, pageY, button, touch) {
  var dx = pageX - _mouseX,
   dy = pageY - _mouseY;

  _phi += dx / _damp;
  // _theta += dy / _damp;

  _phi %= _TWO_PI;
  if (_phi < 0) {
   _phi += _TWO_PI;
  }

  // var maxTheta = _HALF_PI - _HALF_PI * .8,
  //  minTheta = -_HALF_PI + _HALF_PI * .8;

  // if (_theta > maxTheta) {
  //  _theta = maxTheta;
  // } else if (_theta < minTheta) {
  //  _theta = minTheta;
  // }

  updateCamera();
  _dirty = true;
  // updateLabels();
  _mouseX = pageX;
  _mouseY = pageY;
 }
}

function updateCamera() {

 // var radius = _radius + (Math.sin(_theta % _PI)) * 10;
 var radius = _radius;
 var y = radius * Math.sin(_theta),
  phiR = radius * Math.cos(_theta);
 var z = phiR * Math.sin(_phi),
  x = phiR * Math.cos(_phi);

 _camera.position.set(x, y, z);
 _camLight.position.set(x, y, z);
 _camera.lookAt(_center);

}

function updateLabels() {
 if (_sceneScreenshot === null) {
  return;
 }

 var tmpImg = new Image();
 tmpImg.onload = function() {
  _tmpCtx.drawImage(tmpImg, 0, 0, sw, sh);

  var imgData = _tmpCtx.getImageData(0, 0, sw, sh);
  var data = imgData.data;

  var firstXs = [];
  var lastXs = [];
  for (var y = 0; y < sh; y++) {
   var firstX = -1;
   var lastX = -1;
   for (var x = 0; x < sw; x++) {
    var i = (x + y * sw) * 4;
    var sum = data[i] + data[i + 1] + data[i + 2];
    if (firstX === -1) {
     if (sum > 3) {
      firstX = x;
     }
    } else {
     if (sum > 3) {
      lastX = x;
     }
    }
   }
   if (lastX === -1 && firstX >= 0) {
    lastX = firstX;
   }
   firstXs.push(firstX);
   lastXs.push(lastX);
  }
  var firstYs = [];
  var lastYs = [];
  for (var x = 0; x < sw; x++) {
   var firstY = -1;
   var lastY = -1;
   for (var y = 0; y < sh; y++) {
    var i = (x + y * sw) * 4;
    var sum = data[i] + data[i + 1] + data[i + 2];
    if (firstY === -1) {
     if (sum < 759) {
      firstY = y;
     }
    } else {
     if (sum < 759) {
      lastY = y;
     }
    }
   }
   if (lastY === -1 && firstY >= 0) {
    lastY = firstY;
   }
   firstYs.push(firstY);
   lastYs.push(lastY);
  }
  postLoad(firstXs, lastXs, firstYs, lastYs);
 }
 tmpImg.src = _sceneScreenshot;


 function postLoad(firstXs, lastXs, firstYs, lastYs) {

  _tmpCtx.clearRect(0, 0, sw, sh);

  _tmpCtx.beginPath();
  for (var y = 0; y < sh; y++) {
   _tmpCtx.moveTo(firstXs[y], y);
   _tmpCtx.lineTo(lastXs[y], y);
  }
  /* TODO REMOVE BELOW TODO */
  _tmpCtx.strokeStyle = 'black';
  console.log(_tmpCtx.globalAlpha);
  _tmpCtx.stroke();
  /* TODO REMOVE ABOVE TODO */

  _tmpCtx.beginPath();
  for (var x = 0; x < sw; x++) {
   _tmpCtx.moveTo(x, firstYs[x]);
   _tmpCtx.lineTo(x, lastYs[x]);
  }
  /* TODO REMOVE BELOW TODO */
  _tmpCtx.strokeStyle = 'black';
  _tmpCtx.stroke();
  /* TODO REMOVE ABOVE TODO */

  var imgData = _tmpCtx.getImageData(0, 0, sw, sh);
  var data = imgData.data;

  for (var i = 0, iLen = data.length; i < iLen; i += 4) {
   if (data[i + 3] < 200) {
    data[i + 3] = 0;
   }
   /* TODO remove v TODO */
   else { data[i + 3] = 120; }
  }
  _tmpCtx.putImageData(imgData, 0, 0);
 }

}

function animate () {
 cube.rotation.x += 0.001;
 cube.rotation.y += 0.001;

 _renderer.render(_scene, _camera);
 if (_dirty) {
  _sceneScreenshot = _renderer.domElement.toDataURL();
  updateLabels();
  _dirty = false;
 }

 requestAnimationFrame( animate );
}

initialize();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/92/three.js"></script>

<canvas id="scene" width="400" height="300"></canvas>
```

### Failure with Complex Object

- jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xdr9bt0w/

```js
var _PI = Math.PI, _HALF_PI = Math.PI / 2, _TWO_PI = 2 * Math.PI;
var _radius = 10, _damp = 75, _center = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0);
var _phi = _PI / 2, _theta = _theta = 0;
var _sceneScreenshot = null, _dirty = true;

var _tmpCan = document.createElement("canvas"),
 _tmpCtx = _tmpCan.getContext("2d");

var scene = document.getElementById("scene"),
 sw = scene.width, sh = scene.height;
var _scene = new THREE.Scene();
var _renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ canvas: scene, alpha: true, antialias: true });
_renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
_renderer.setSize(sw, sh);
var _camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(35, sw / sh, .1, 1000);

_tmpCan.width = sw; _tmpCan.height = sh;

_scene.add(new THREE.HemisphereLight(0x999999, 0x555555, 1));
_scene.add(new THREE.AmbientLight(0x404040));
var _camLight = new THREE.PointLight(0xdfdfdf, 1.8, 300, 2);
_scene.add(_camLight);

var geometry = new THREE.BoxBufferGeometry( 1, 1, 1 );
var material = new THREE.MeshPhysicalMaterial( { color: 0x2378d3, opacity: .7 } );
var cube = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
_scene.add( cube );

var geometry = new THREE.BoxBufferGeometry( 1, 1, 1 );
var material = new THREE.MeshPhysicalMaterial( { color: 0xc36843, opacity: .7 } );
var cube2 = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
cube2.position.x = -.75;
cube2.position.y = .75
_scene.add( cube2 );

var geometry = new THREE.BoxBufferGeometry( 1, 1, 1 );
var material = new THREE.MeshPhysicalMaterial( { color: 0x43f873, opacity: .7 } );
var cube3 = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
cube3.position.x = -.25;
cube3.position.y = 1.5;
_scene.add( cube3 );


var geometry = new THREE.BoxBufferGeometry( 1, 1, 1 );
var material = new THREE.MeshPhysicalMaterial( { color: 0x253621, opacity: .7 } );
var cube4 = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
cube4.position.x = 1;
cube4.position.y = .35;
_scene.add( cube4 );

function initialize() {
 document.body.appendChild(_tmpCan);
 _tmpCan.style.position = "absolute";
 _tmpCan.style.left = "200px";
 _tmpCan.style.top = "0px";
 _tmpCan.style.pointerEvents = "none";
 addListeners();
 updateCamera();
 animate();
}

function addListeners() {
 /* mouse events */

 var scene = document.getElementById("scene");

 scene.oncontextmenu = function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
 }

 scene.onmousedown = function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  mouseTouchDown(e.pageX, e.pageY, e.button);
 }

 scene.ontouchstart = function(e) {
  if (e.touches.length !== 1) {
   return;
  }
  e.preventDefault();
  mouseTouchDown(e.touches[0].pageX, e.touches[0].pageY, e.touches.length, true);
 }

 function mouseTouchDown(pageX, pageY, button, touch) {
  _mouseX = pageX; _mouseY = pageY;
  _button = button;
  if (touch) {
   document.ontouchmove = function(e) {
    if (e.touches.length !== 1) {
     return;
    }
    mouseTouchMove(e.touches[0].pageX, e.touches[0].pageY, e.touches.length, true);
   }
   document.ontouchend = function() {
    document.ontouchmove = null;
    document.ontouchend = null;
   }
  } else {
   document.onmousemove = function(e) {
    mouseTouchMove(e.pageX, e.pageY, _button);
   }
   document.onmouseup = function() {
    document.onmousemove = null;
    document.onmouseup = null;
   }
  }
 }

 function mouseTouchMove(pageX, pageY, button, touch) {
  var dx = pageX - _mouseX,
   dy = pageY - _mouseY;

  _phi += dx / _damp;
  // _theta += dy / _damp;

  _phi %= _TWO_PI;
  if (_phi < 0) {
   _phi += _TWO_PI;
  }

  // var maxTheta = _HALF_PI - _HALF_PI * .8,
  //  minTheta = -_HALF_PI + _HALF_PI * .8;

  // if (_theta > maxTheta) {
  //  _theta = maxTheta;
  // } else if (_theta < minTheta) {
  //  _theta = minTheta;
  // }

  updateCamera();
  _dirty = true;
  // updateLabels();
  _mouseX = pageX;
  _mouseY = pageY;
 }
}

function updateCamera() {

 // var radius = _radius + (Math.sin(_theta % _PI)) * 10;
 var radius = _radius;
 var y = radius * Math.sin(_theta),
  phiR = radius * Math.cos(_theta);
 var z = phiR * Math.sin(_phi),
  x = phiR * Math.cos(_phi);

 _camera.position.set(x, y, z);
 _camLight.position.set(x, y, z);
 _camera.lookAt(_center);

}

function updateLabels() {
 if (_sceneScreenshot === null) {
  return;
 }

 var tmpImg = new Image();
 tmpImg.onload = function() {
  _tmpCtx.drawImage(tmpImg, 0, 0, sw, sh);

  var imgData = _tmpCtx.getImageData(0, 0, sw, sh);
  var data = imgData.data;

  var firstXs = [];
  var lastXs = [];
  for (var y = 0; y < sh; y++) {
   var firstX = -1;
   var lastX = -1;
   for (var x = 0; x < sw; x++) {
    var i = (x + y * sw) * 4;
    var sum = data[i] + data[i + 1] + data[i + 2];
    if (firstX === -1) {
     if (sum > 3) {
      firstX = x;
     }
    } else {
     if (sum > 3) {
      lastX = x;
     }
    }
   }
   if (lastX === -1 && firstX >= 0) {
    lastX = firstX;
   }
   firstXs.push(firstX);
   lastXs.push(lastX);
  }
  var firstYs = [];
  var lastYs = [];
  for (var x = 0; x < sw; x++) {
   var firstY = -1;
   var lastY = -1;
   for (var y = 0; y < sh; y++) {
    var i = (x + y * sw) * 4;
    var sum = data[i] + data[i + 1] + data[i + 2];
    if (firstY === -1) {
     if (sum > 3) {
      firstY = y;
     }
    } else {
     if (sum > 3) {
      lastY = y;
     }
    }
   }
   if (lastY === -1 && firstY >= 0) {
    lastY = firstY;
   }
   firstYs.push(firstY);
   lastYs.push(lastY);
  }
  postLoad(firstXs, lastXs, firstYs, lastYs);
 }
 tmpImg.src = _sceneScreenshot;


 function postLoad(firstXs, lastXs, firstYs, lastYs) {

  _tmpCtx.clearRect(0, 0, sw, sh);

  _tmpCtx.beginPath();
  for (var y = 0; y < sh; y++) {
   _tmpCtx.moveTo(firstXs[y], y);
   _tmpCtx.lineTo(lastXs[y], y);
  }
  /* TODO REMOVE BELOW TODO */
  _tmpCtx.strokeStyle = 'black';
  console.log(_tmpCtx.globalAlpha);
  _tmpCtx.stroke();
  /* TODO REMOVE ABOVE TODO */

  _tmpCtx.beginPath();
  for (var x = 0; x < sw; x++) {
   _tmpCtx.moveTo(x, firstYs[x]);
   _tmpCtx.lineTo(x, lastYs[x]);
  }
  /* TODO REMOVE BELOW TODO */
  _tmpCtx.strokeStyle = 'black';
  _tmpCtx.stroke();
  /* TODO REMOVE ABOVE TODO */

  var imgData = _tmpCtx.getImageData(0, 0, sw, sh);
  var data = imgData.data;

  for (var i = 0, iLen = data.length; i < iLen; i += 4) {
   if (data[i + 3] < 200) {
    data[i + 3] = 0;
   }
   /* TODO remove v TODO */
   else { data[i + 3] = 120; }
  }
  _tmpCtx.putImageData(imgData, 0, 0);
 }

}

function animate () {
 cube.rotation.x += 0.001;
 cube.rotation.y += 0.001;
    
    cube2.rotation.x -= 0.001;
 cube2.rotation.y += 0.001;
    
    cube3.rotation.x += 0.001;
 cube3.rotation.y -= 0.001;
    
    cube4.rotation.x -= 0.001;
 cube4.rotation.y -= 0.001;

 _renderer.render(_scene, _camera);
 if (_dirty) {
  _sceneScreenshot = _renderer.domElement.toDataURL();
  updateLabels();
  _dirty = false;
 }

 requestAnimationFrame( animate );
}

initialize();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/92/three.js"></script>
<canvas id="scene" width="400" height="300"></canvas>
```

You can see with the above jsfiddle that the inside of this complex, convex image fails on the inside.

### Question

Therefore, the question remains: what is a good way of creating a mask, if you will, of the image (disregarding holes) that will cover all of the outside of any complex/convex object where the background is white and the components of the image are anything but white? thanks

Comment: So, to clarify, you are looking for a way to create a mask from a rendered image, and removing any holes inside it?

Comment: @Jave, I guess that is one way of thinking about it, yes. That is exactly what I am looking to do, but I guess I was going about it the more complex way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a solution that uses a [flood-fill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill) algorithm to cover the outer areas with white and the rest with black.
Keep in mind that this is a very naive implementation, there are lots of optimization that can potentially be done (by calculating the bounding rectangle and only filling inside it for example, another one would be to use [32-bit arrays](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2011/12/faster-canvas-pixel-manipulation-with-typed-arrays/) to do the actual pixel assignment while filling).
Another thing to note is that the filling always starts in the upper left corner, if the object is currently covering that pixel it will not work (you can however pick another pixel to start at).

I removed the touch handlers and some other items to keep the example short.
The `updateMask`-function is where the mask is created.

```js
function createCube(color, x, y){
    const geo = new THREE.BoxBufferGeometry( 1, 1, 1 );
    const mat = new THREE.MeshPhysicalMaterial( { color: color, opacity: 1 } );
    const mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geo, mat);
    mesh.position.x = x;
    mesh.position.y = y;
    return mesh;
}

const c_main = document.getElementById("main");
const c_mask = document.getElementById("mask");
const ctx_mask = c_mask.getContext("2d");
ctx_mask.fillStyle = "#000";
const cw = c_main.width, ch = c_main.height;

const TWO_PI = Math.PI * 2;
const damp = 75, radius = 10, animspeed = 0.001;
const center = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0);
let x1 = 0;
let phi = Math.PI / 2;

const scene = new THREE.Scene();
const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(35, cw / ch, 0.1, 1000);
const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ canvas: c_main, alpha: true, antialias: false });
renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
renderer.setSize(cw, ch);
const camLight = new THREE.PointLight(0xdfdfdf, 1.8, 300, 2);
scene.add(new THREE.HemisphereLight(0x999999, 0x555555, 1));
scene.add(new THREE.AmbientLight(0x404040));
scene.add(camLight);
const cubes = [];
cubes.push(createCube(0x2378d3, 0, 0));
cubes.push(createCube(0xc36843, -0.75, 0.75));
cubes.push(createCube(0x43f873, -0.25, 1.5));
cubes.push(createCube(0x253621, 1, 0.35));
scene.add(...cubes);

function initialize() {
    c_main.addEventListener("mousedown", mouseDown, false);
    updateCamera();
    animate();
}

function updateMask(){
    //First, fill the canvas with black
    ctx_mask.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
    ctx_mask.fillRect(0,0, cw, ch);
    //Then using the composite operation "destination-in" the canvas is made transparent EXCEPT where the new image is drawn.
    ctx_mask.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-in";
    ctx_mask.drawImage(c_main, 0, 0);

    //Now, use a flood fill algorithm of your choice to fill the outer transparent field with white.
    const idata = ctx_mask.getImageData(0,0, cw, ch);
    const array = idata.data;
    floodFill(array, 0, 0, cw, ch);
    ctx_mask.putImageData(idata, 0, 0);

    //The only transparency left are in the "holes", we make these black by using the composite operation "destination-over" to paint black behind everything.
    ctx_mask.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-over";
    ctx_mask.fillRect(0,0, cw, ch);
}

function mouseDown(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    x1 = e.pageX;
    const button = e.button;

    document.addEventListener("mousemove", mouseMove, false);
    document.addEventListener("mouseup", mouseUp, false);
}
function mouseUp(){
    document.removeEventListener("mousemove", mouseMove, false);
    document.removeEventListener("mouseup", mouseUp, false);
}
function mouseMove(e){
    const x2 = e.pageX;
    const dx = x2 - x1;

    phi += dx/damp;
    phi %= TWO_PI;
    if( phi < 0 ){
      phi += TWO_PI;
    }

    x1 = x2;
    updateCamera();
}


function updateCamera() {
    const x = radius * Math.cos(phi);
    const y = 0;
    const z = radius * Math.sin(phi);

    camera.position.set(x, y, z);
    camera.lookAt(center);
    camLight.position.set(x, y, z);
}
function animate(){
    cubes[0].rotation.x += animspeed;
    cubes[0].rotation.y += animspeed;
    cubes[1].rotation.x -= animspeed;
    cubes[1].rotation.y += animspeed;
    cubes[2].rotation.x += animspeed;
    cubes[2].rotation.y -= animspeed;
    cubes[3].rotation.x -= animspeed;
    cubes[3].rotation.y -= animspeed;

    renderer.render(scene, camera);
    updateMask();

    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}

const FILL_THRESHOLD = 254;
//Quickly adapted flood fill from http://www.adammil.net/blog/v126_A_More_Efficient_Flood_Fill.html

function floodStart(array, x, y, width, height){
    const M = width * 4;
    while(true){
    let ox = x, oy = y;
    while(y !== 0 && array[(y-1)*M + x*4 + 3] < FILL_THRESHOLD){ y--; }
    while(x !== 0 && array[y*M + (x-1)*4 + 3] < FILL_THRESHOLD){ x--; }
    if(x === ox && y === oy){ break; }
  }

  floodFill(array, x, y, width, height);
}

function floodFill(array, x, y, width, height){
    const M = width * 4;

    let lastRowLength = 0;
  do{
    let rowLength = 0, sx = x;
    let idx = y*M + x*4 + 3;
    if(lastRowLength !== 0 && array[idx] >= FILL_THRESHOLD){
      do{
        if(--lastRowLength === 0){ return; }
      }
      while(array[ y*M + (++x)*4 + 3]);
      sx = x;
    }
    else{
      for(; x !== 0 && array[y*M + (x-1)*4 + 3] < FILL_THRESHOLD; rowLength++, lastRowLength++){
        const idx = y*M + (--x)*4;
        array[idx] = 255;
        array[idx + 1] = 255;
        array[idx + 2] = 255;
        array[idx + 3] = 255;
        if( y !== 0 && array[(y-1)*M + x*4 + 3] < FILL_THRESHOLD ){
          floodStart(array, x, y-1, width, height);
        }
        }
    }

    for(; sx < width && array[y*M + sx*4 + 3] < FILL_THRESHOLD; rowLength++, sx++){
        const idx = y*M + sx*4;
      array[idx] = 255;
      array[idx + 1] = 255;
      array[idx + 2] = 255;
      array[idx + 3] = 255;
    }
    if(rowLength < lastRowLength){
      for(let end=x+lastRowLength; ++sx < end; ){
        if(array[y*M + sx*4 + 3] < FILL_THRESHOLD){
            floodFill(array, sx, y, width, height);
        }
      }
    }
    else if(rowLength > lastRowLength && y !== 0){
      for(let ux=x+lastRowLength; ++ux<sx; ){
        if(array[(y-1)*M + ux*4 + 3] < FILL_THRESHOLD){
            floodStart(array, ux, y-1, width, height);
        }
      }
    }
    lastRowLength = rowLength;
  }
  while(lastRowLength !== 0 && ++y < height);
}

initialize();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/92/three.js"></script>
<canvas id="main" width="300" height="200"></canvas>
<canvas id="mask" width="300" height="200"></canvas>
```

Comment: sweet, Jave. Thank you! I think I will use this since relatively small canvas (well, sort of 400x300), but it does not seem super efficient. Then again, my method is worse! I appreciate it; thanks; good luck.

Comment: Jave, do you know of a good way of getting each x,y point that would construct the boundaries of this object?

Comment: @dylnmc You can probably project the meshes using the camera matrix and then somehow trace the outline edges. Although I am not sure exactly how to do that.

Comment: jave, awesome; I am looking into it. bai on freenode/#threejs just helped me, and it appears as though I can pass an override material to the renderer (for example pass `MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0 })`). Then, apparently, there is a blocking call (`readPixels()`) that will read in the pixels and might be preferable to my method of recalling the pixels. Finally re-render normally. Hopefully, this method will work. Nonetheless, you did an excellent job with this question. Thank you so much.